# How to see the full set of parameters that fail a parameterized test in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4, parameterized-unit-test

I have a test class that uses `org.junit.runners.Parameterized`. How can I identify the full set of parameters out of the set of three that fails in a test in IntelliJ 14?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[1]` on the left side is the **index** of your parameters array that has failed in your test. So go to your test class, look up your parameters for that test, and the second (`[1]` in a zero-based array) parameters entry is the one that failed your test.

Answer (score 1):

Each set of parameters has its own name - the `[1]` on the left side is that name.

You can use `name` argument in `@Parameters` to customize that name, for example:

```
@Parameters(name = "{index}: testAdd({0}+{1}) = {2}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {1, 1, 2},
            {2, 2, 4},
    });
}
```

that way, in the square brackets on the left, next to the test name, you will see `[0: testAdd(1+1=2)]` and `[1: testAdd(2+2=4)]`.

By default `name={index}`, and that's why you see `[0]`, `[1]`... in the square brackets.